# Why isn't my smooth scrolling smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the following code to smooth scroll down a fairly large document:

```
$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: $('#article').offset().top + $('#article').outerHeight(true)
}, 500);
```

I believe this is because the its spanning too great of a distance. On smaller articles (i.e. instances where the div #article takes up less height) it scrolls smoothly.  Is there a dynamic way to adjust the scrolling time to avoid choppy displays, or is there some other solution?

Comment: you can always use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-utility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple equation between article height and duration .. for example you can set the duration like this .. or change it up to your need

```
//this is just for example
var duration = ($('#article').outerHeight(true) / 100) * 500 ;
//or
//var duration = (($('#article').offset().top + $('#article').outerHeight(true)) / 100) * 500 ;

$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: $('#article').offset().top + $('#article').outerHeight(true)
}, duration);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2uun7rqb/2/) .. change #article height in css to see the effect